# Select with content_tag not displaying include_blank

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to display a empty option for a select option, using it:

```
  <%= form.select(:group_id, include_blank: true) do %>

    <% @groups.each do |group| %>
      <%= content_tag(:option, group.name, value: group.id) %>
    <% end %>

  <% end %>
```

This don't get any error, but not display too.

Comment: From the docs https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/select, I was not able to solve it. neither found others questions in stack-overflow that lead to the solution. The head of the form is <%= form_with(model: @transaction) do |form| %>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Weird one, but I believe your `include_blank` wasn't being passed in the right position. This is working for me.

```
  <%= form.select(:group_id, nil, { include_blank: 'Please select' }) do %>
    <% @groups.each do |group| %>
      <%= content_tag(:option, group[:name], value: group[:id]) %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
```